# Magento 2.1.2 static content not generating

Tags: magento2

I have the site set to developer mode, 
I have verified write-ability to all var/ directories.
Clear cache and generation.

Verified write-ability to pub and pub/static.   Nothing.....  No static files generate at all. cleared everything except .htaccess from pub/static.   So I have no css, style information, and connot navigate to admin or any other page, as if mode_rewrite is not installed or permitted.  I have set all directives to allow all in apache configs for .htaccess to work.

I have even tried setting everything to 777 permissions.

There are no errors that I can tell.

Comment: You created a new theme? All default themes had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below step.

```
Remove pub/static
Remove var/cache
Remove var/composer_home
Remove var/generation
Remove var/page_cache
Remove var/view_preprocessed
```

And then Try to run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

1. how do you deploy the static content?
2. Have you set less compilation to server-side compilation oder client-side compilation?
3. Do you use grunt?
4. Can you create symlinks?

Try to deploy the static content via `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

If you don't you en_US as your locale you should always also include it in the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` or whatever your locale is

If you use grunt for less compilation you can run into issues if you use virtual box with shared folder and Windows Host. Using VirtualBox with Linux guest, Windows host and shared folders activated has the issue that symlinks don't work, because of the windows file system. Using grunt for less compilation creates symlinks, thus being not able to create these because of the issue I mentioned.

Please give us more information about your system